# Android google map single polyline or multiple

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2, google-polyline

I have a best practices question on how to manage adding a polyline path to a GoogleMap in android, that grows as the user moves.

**TLDR version**: Is it better to keep replacing the polyline with a new one that is all the previous points plus the new one, or to keep adding a ton of 2 point polylines?

In previous iterations, I've created a new 2 point polyline for every new location, where the start of it is at the end of the previous line, and the end of it at the current location.

I came to the realization that I could be creating MANY resources for the map to have to keep track of instead of just one. Because of this, I've looked into how to make a single line and just add points to it (that doesn't seem to work), and there isn't any documentation that I can find that says how I might achieve this.

I have currently landed on this solution:

```kotlin
private lateinit var polyLine: Polyline
fun updateLocation(location: Location?) {
    location?.let {
        val latLng = LatLng(location!!.latitude, location!!.longitude)
        if (firstLoc) {
            polyLine = googleMap.addPolyline(PolylineOptions().add(latLng))
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16F))
            firstLoc = false;
        } else {
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16F))
            val newLine = googleMap.addPolyline(PolylineOptions().addAll(polyLine.points).add(latLng).width(10f))
            polyLine.remove()
            polyLine = newLine
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows the map to only have to deal with one line at a time. My main question is whether or not this is worse, due to having to recreate all the points on the new line every time?
Running in my emulator, and my actual device, it seems fine. There's no flickering (which makes sense, it's adding the new line before removing the old one), and there doesn't appear to be any lag.

My current plan is to continue how it is, because it's simple, and appears to work. But I'd want to make sure I'm not causing more work than I need. It seems like there's a bit of work that needs to happen in either case, but this way seemed to me to be the better route.

Comment: You are missing a third option, which I prefer: As you keep already a reference to the Polyline, why don't you just replace the LatLng coordinates (kept in a separate growing List) using Polyline.setPoints().

Comment: Oh interesting, I saw that method, but I didn't try it because addPoint didn't work for me at all. I will attempt setPoints and see if that works. Just to be clear, I'd be calling setPoints on every location update, passing in the whole growing list? This solution sounds like it'll also fix the issue I just found, where my current solution doesn't update the poly line when my screen is off, despite the foreground service.

Comment: Yes, I am calling setPoints with the full list, whenever (which is once a second in my case) the list receives an additional point. BTW: I am hiding the difference between the first time creation of the Polyline and the subsequent updates in a separate class, which I named PolylineHolder. This class cares for creating the polyline and keeping a reference, when it receives the first point, and calls the setPoints method of the reference for subsequent updates. The client then does not need to distinguish between the first and subsequent updates.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! I've updated to use setpoints, but haven't been out to test it yet. Seems to work fine on my  emulator though. If you wouldn't mind making your suggestion an answer, and I'll accept it. It really does seem to me to be the best option.